# django register user with django-facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook

Ok I see everyone saying use django-facebook, and it says it can do everything I want.
I have it installed on my app and the example page works, but how do I actually register a user with it?
Apart from the installation all the rest of the docs seem autogenerated and I have yet to find a step by step guide as to how to register a user on my site using django-facebook.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/tree/master/facebook_example) is a working example of facebook auth with django.

Facebook uses [OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) to federate user logins. An OAuth2 authorization step-by-step consists of

1. Create an authorization token by calling the request-token url with your consumer keys
2. Send the user to the authorize url with the token that you created and a callback url
3. Once authorized the user will be redirected to your callback url with an auth-token
4. Convert the auth-token to an access token at the request-token url
5. Save the access token and use it to make authorized requests

Comment: That explains how OAuth2 works, that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how do I use django-facebook to facilaitate that process. The link to the example project you posted doesn't have any documentation included.